# how to verticall align divs with float:left?

Tags: css

I have this kind of structure....

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="section_3 row">
    <div class="image_info_carousel_left col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

      <h1>Stay organized with your personal moving dashboard</h1>
      <div class="author">Get timely reminders and assign tasks to stay on top of your move</div>
    </div>

    <div class="info_image col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <img src="css/img/realtor-fourth.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this type of css....

```css
.image_info_carousel_left {
    padding: 100px 50px !important;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3B4C60;
}

.info_image {
    padding: 0;
}
```

The height of the image within the image_info class varies dynamically... so the height of the image_info_carousel_left should also change & and the `<h1>` and `<div class="author">` should be vertically centered...

I have tried using display:table & display:table-cell, but it doesn't work as classes with col-lg- are having float:left...

how can I do this?

Comment: Please, provide a demo([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dbg284y7/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

this is the formula for vertical align anything.

```
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Just put those commands to div you want to vertically align, or create a mixin if you are using preprocessors

I created this example to see it working with floats:

http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/NxGROP

Comment: Its because you have given the fixed height for container.....so it can count the 50% of the container...but what if we haven't given height to the container and it has to be adjusted dynamically.....then it wont be possible to get the 50% value...assume box-1 with the dynamic image size and box-2 with fixed height....then how would it be possible?

Comment: Then try flexbox:
link: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:middle;` and don't forget to [remove extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which occurred by `display:inline-block;`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/dbg284y7/1/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}
.box1 {
  background: blue;
}
.box2 {
  background: blue;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1 box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div><!--
  --><div class="box2 box">heading with the fixed height</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution..it works well as it is written...but it doesn't work with float:left.....

Comment: @SohilShah It is not possible to get your desire situation by `float`.

Comment: @SohilShah Can you explain why you need float:left? In your question it sounds like the classes just have float:left by default, so you could simply override that with float:none, but that is not an option?